# Dismissible widget not changing when using Unique Key

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dismissible

So I'm trying to use a dismissible widget as part of my Flutter code. It works fine, except when I swipe to before the first document, or after the last document. Below is the code sample I've used:

```
StreamBuilder <QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: _firestore.collection('articles').snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(child: Text("Error fetching posts ${snapshot.error}"),);
            }
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = snapshot.data.documents;
              return GestureDetector(
                onHorizontalDragUpdate: (dragUpdateDetails) {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WebViewContainer(documents[index].data['url'])));              },
                child: Dismissible(
                  key: Key(index.toString()),
                  direction: DismissDirection.vertical,
                  onDismissed: (direction) {
                    setState(() {
                      documents.removeAt(index);
                      index = (index==documents.length -1) ? index = 0 : index++;
                    });
                  },
```

The code runs fine till I reach the ends of the list of the documents. The error message I got was the following:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building Dismissible-[<'0'>](dirty, state: _DismissibleState#6b64c(tickers: tracking 2 tickers)):
A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree.


Make sure to implement the onDismissed handler and to immediately remove the Dismissible widget from the application once that handler has fired.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Dismissible-[<'0'>] file:///C:/Users/Lenovo/AndroidStudioProjects/sevenlines/lib/widgets/newspage.dart:63:24
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _DismissibleState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/dismissible.dart:526:11)
#1      _DismissibleState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/dismissible.dart:535:8)
#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4334:27)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4223:15)
#4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Dismissible-[<'0'>] file:///C:/Users/Lenovo/AndroidStudioProjects/sevenlines/lib/widgets/newspage.dart:63:24
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Upon checking for solutions to this issue, I decided to switch from an index-dependent key to a UniqueKey. But now it doesn't  move across the list at all - the page stays at the first document itself. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ObjectKey not Key in  `key: Key(index.toString()),` and put as param your object data.

Comment: Sorry but I get the same output as the UniqueKey i.e. the page stays at the first document itself. I used key:ObjectKey(documents[index]);

Comment: Are you use statefull or stateless widget?

Comment: I'm using a stateful widget.

Comment: Let`s check is problem with Dismissible. Can you change code for delete item by double tap?

Comment: How do I do that? Delete item is being done by dismissible right, not the Gesture Detector.